# Querying avro data files stored in Azure Data Lake directly with raw SQL from Databricks

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Databricks Notebooks to read avro files stored in an Azure Data Lake Gen2. The avro files are created by an Event Hub Capture, and present a specific schema. From these files I have to extract only the Body field, where the data which I'm interested in is actually stored.

I already implented this in Python and it works as expected:

```
path = 'abfss://file_system@storage_account.dfs.core.windows.net/root/YYYY/MM/DD/HH/mm/file.avro'
df0 = spark.read.format('avro').load(path) # 1
df1 = df0.select(df0.Body.cast('string')) # 2
rdd1 = df1.rdd.map(lambda x: x[0]) # 3
data = spark.read.json(rdd1) # 4
```

Now I need to translate this to raw SQL in order to filter the data directly in the SQL query. Considering the 4 steps above, steps 1 and 2 with SQL are as follows:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW file_avro
USING avro
OPTIONS (path "abfss://file_system@storage_account.dfs.core.windows.net/root/YYYY/MM/DD/HH/mm/file.avro")

WITH body_array AS (SELECT cast(Body AS STRING) FROM file_avro)

SELECT * FROM body_array
```

With this partial query I get the same as df1 above (step 2 with Python):

```
Body
[{"id":"a123","group":"0","value":1.0,"timestamp":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.0000000"},
{"id":"a123","group":"0","value":1.5,"timestamp":"2020-01-01T00:01:00.0000000"},
{"id":"a123","group":"0","value":2.3,"timestamp":"2020-01-01T00:02:00.0000000"},
{"id":"a123","group":"0","value":1.8,"timestamp":"2020-01-01T00:03:00.0000000"}]
[{"id":"b123","group":"0","value":2.0,"timestamp":"2020-01-01T00:00:01.0000000"},
{"id":"b123","group":"0","value":1.2,"timestamp":"2020-01-01T00:01:01.0000000"},
{"id":"b123","group":"0","value":2.1,"timestamp":"2020-01-01T00:02:01.0000000"},
{"id":"b123","group":"0","value":1.7,"timestamp":"2020-01-01T00:03:01.0000000"}]
...
```

I need to know how to introduce the steps 3 and 4 into the SQL query, to parse the strings into json objects and finally get the desired dataframe with columns id, group, value and timestamp. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way I found to do this with raw SQL is as follows, using from_json Spark SQL built-in function and the scheme of the Body field:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW file_avro
USING avro
OPTIONS (path "abfss://file_system@storage_account.dfs.core.windows.net/root/YYYY/MM/DD/HH/mm/file.avro")

WITH body_array AS (SELECT cast(Body AS STRING) FROM file_avro),
data1 AS (SELECT from_json(Body, 'array<struct<id:string,group:string,value:double,timestamp:timestamp>>') FROM body_array),
data2 AS (SELECT explode(*) FROM data1),
data3 AS (SELECT col.* FROM data2)
SELECT * FROM data3 WHERE id = "a123"     --FILTERING BY CHANNEL ID
```

It performs faster than the Python code I posted in the question, surely because of the use of from_json and the scheme of Body to extract data inside it. My version of this approach in PySpark looks as follows:

```
path = 'abfss://file_system@storage_account.dfs.core.windows.net/root/YYYY/MM/DD/HH/mm/file.avro'
df0 = spark.read.format('avro').load(path)
df1 = df0.selectExpr("cast(Body as string) as json_data")
df2 = df1.selectExpr("from_json(json_data, 'array<struct<id:string,group:string,value:double,timestamp:timestamp>>') as parsed_json")
data = df2.selectExpr("explode(parsed_json) as json").select("json.*")
```